# Using Bitwise in C, rotate x to the right by 4

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

No loops are allowed.
The only operators allowed are ~ & ^ | + << >> !

Rotate x to the right by 4.

Examples: rotate4(0x87654321) = 0x18765432

Max ops: 12

```
int rotate4(int x){
    CODE
```

I have

```
int rotate4(int x){
    return (x << 28) | (x >> 4);
```

This is outputting a negative number that seems to be correct, but negative.

Test: Answer should be 134217728[0x80000000]

My Answer is -134217728[0xf8000000]

My though process is:

x << moves the 4 LSB code to the left 28 spaces meaning the 4 LSB will be left in the MSB position.

x >> 4 drops off the 4 LSB so that the 4 MSB are 0s.

Is my code producing the wrong result because it is right shifting arithmetically?

Comment: When it comes to: **"The result of E1 >> E2"** the standard says: **" If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the
resulting value is implementation-defined."** In other words... you can get any result - no one can tell. Use unsigned types instead....

Comment: What happens if you change `int` to `unsigned`?

Comment: @SupportUkraine This appears to be a task in CS:APP where the types can't be changed. Need to work around signedness restriction.

Comment: The size of `int` is not set in stone, so the result is not either. If you used a signed type, then the example `rotate4(0x87654321) = 0x18765432` is simply not true. The assignment seems to be poorly defined.

Comment: @iBug well, I pretty sure this can't be done in a standard compliant way with predictable result if the type is `int`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644362/are-the-results-of-bitwise-operations-on-signed-integers-defined

Comment: Even homework specifications have undefined behavior in C.

Comment: A similar homework exercise was discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928659/rotating-bits-of-any-integer-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Left shifting data in a signed `int` beyond bit 30 invokes undefined behavior - you'll be shifting data into the sign bit. This is one of many reasons why we should pretty much *never* use signed operands to the bitwise operators.

In your case, you can't even store `0x87654321` inside an `int` because it's already too large before the shift.

Change to `unsigned int` or better yet `uint32_t`. Then this should give the result `0x18765432`.