# C printing bits

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program in C that prints bits of int.
for some reason i get wrong values,

```
void printBits(unsigned int num){
    unsigned int size = sizeof(unsigned int);
    unsigned int maxPow = 1<<(size*8-1);
    printf("MAX POW : %u\n",maxPow);
    int i=0,j;
    for(;i<size;++i){
        for(j=0;j<8;++j){
            // print last bit and shift left.
            printf("%u ",num&maxPow);
            num = num<<1;
        }
    }
}
```

My question, **first** why am i getting this result (for printBits(3)).

> MAX POW : 2147483648 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 2147483648 214748364 8

**second** is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Is this what you want?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024389/print-an-int-in-binary-representation-using-c

Comment: Is that really the output, or is the formatting broken? It doesn't match the print statements ... Oh, and you don't say what value you're passing in for `num`, either

Comment: @Useless fixed question, output is for printBits(3).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are calculating the result correctly, but you are not *printing* it right. Also you do not need a second loop:

```
for(;i<size*8;++i){
    // print last bit and shift left.
    printf("%u ",num&maxPow ? 1 : 0);
    num = num<<1;
}
```

If you'd like to show off, you could replace the conditional with two exclamation points:

```
printf("%u ", !!(num&maxPow));
```

Comment: Please don't spell `!!` like that. It's hard to read. Spell it like `n > 0` or `n!=0` since conditional operators evaluate to ints in C.

Answer (score 11):

To address point two, I'd consider the following, which is simplified a bit for ease of understanding.

```
void printBits(unsigned int num)
{
   for(int bit=0;bit<(sizeof(unsigned int) * 8); bit++)
   {
      printf("%i ", num & 0x01);
      num = num >> 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand endianess, but am I right thinking that this prints bits in "big endian", as opposed to "little endian" which is more common? E.g. `1 0 0 0 0 0 0` for the number `1` in 8-bits, as opposed to `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1` for the same number in little endian.

Comment: The value 1 in 16 bits it will either be 00000000 00000001 or  00000001 00000000 depending on Endianess. It is not mirrored like in your example.

Comment: It prints the values vice versed.

Answer (score 10):

The result you get is because `num&maxPow` is either 0 or `maxPow`. To print 1 instead of `maxPow`, you could use `printf("%u ", num&maxPow ? 1 : 0);`. An alternative way to print the bits is

```
while(maxPow){
    printf("%u ", num&maxPow ? 1 : 0);
    maxPow >>= 1;
}
```

i.e. shifting the bitmask right instead of `num` left. The loop ends when the set bit of the mask gets shifted out.

Comment: you are correct, shifting the bitmask might seem more intuative them shifting the number.

Answer (score 4):

How about this Macro:

```
#define print_bits(x)                                            \
  do {                                                           \
    unsigned long long a__ = (x);                                \
    size_t bits__ = sizeof(x) * 8;                               \
    printf(#x ": ");                                             \
    while (bits__--) putchar(a__ &(1ULL << bits__) ? '1' : '0'); \
    putchar('\n');                                               \
  } while (0)

char c = 3;
int i = -1;
print_bits(c);
print_bits(i);
```

output:

```
c: 00000011
i: 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

This Marco can be used on any primitive datatype and the expression 'x' will be evaluated only once. So you should be safe from side effects.

With the [typeof construct](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) you could extend this to structures too:

```
#define print_bits(x)                                             \
  do {                                                            \
    typeof(x) a__ = (x);                                          \
    char *p__ = (char *)&a__ + sizeof(x) - 1;                     \
    size_t bytes__ = sizeof(x);                                   \
    printf(#x ": ");                                              \
    while (bytes__--) {                                           \
      char bits__ = 8;                                            \
      while (bits__--) putchar(*p__ & (1 << bits__) ? '1' : '0'); \
      p__--;                                                      \
    }                                                             \
    putchar('\n');                                                \
  } while (0)

print_bits((struct in_addr){.s_addr = 0xff00ff00});
```

output:

```
(struct in_addr){.s_addr = 0xff00ff00}: 11111111000000001111111100000000
```

Could be useful e.g. in print debugging.

(`typeof` is a GNU-extension, use `__typeof__` instead if it must work in ISO C programs)

Comment: This isn't portable, and using double-underscores before an identifier name is undefined behavior.

Comment: Might be off topic but do you know what's the 'standard' way to avoid confusion with identifiers within a macro and why this isn't portable? Thx

Comment: I usually suffix (rather than prefix) with an underscore or two. `typeof` is a GNU C extension. You can use `unsigned long long` and take the size of `x` instead of `a`. (also, a single underscore prefix is reserved for file scope so you could probably use that, too)

Answer (score 1):

```
void print_bits(unsigned int x)
{
    int i;
    for(i=8*sizeof(x)-1; i>=0; i--) {
        (x & (1 << i)) ? putchar('1') : putchar('0');
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: It won't work for unsigned long. 1 << 64 is .... 1 on Intel.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018469/why-does-1ul-64-return-1-instead-of-0

Comment: The unsigned int argument type makes this useless.

Answer (score 1):

I guess You can remove some code and

```
void printB(unsigned int num){
    unsigned int size = sizeof(unsigned int);
    int i;
    for(i = size*8-1; i>= 0; i--){
        printf("%u",(num >>i) & 1 );
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```c
// example code `ch7-8.c` from the book `明解C言語 3nd` of Shibata Bouyou

#include<stdio.h>

int count_bits(unsigned x)
{
    int bits = 0;
    while (x) {
        if (x & 1U) bits++;
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return bits;
}

int int_bits(void)
{
    return count_bits(~0U);
}

void print_nbits(unsigned x, unsigned n)
{
    int i = int_bits();
    i = (n < i) ? n - 1 : i - 1;
    for (; i >= 0; i--)
        putchar(((x >> i) & 1U) ? '1' : '0');
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 65535U; i++) {
        printf("%5u ", i);
        print_nbits(i, 16);
        printf(" %06o %04X\n", i, i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
    0 0000000000000000 000000 0000
    1 0000000000000001 000001 0001
    2 0000000000000010 000002 0002
    3 0000000000000011 000003 0003
    4 0000000000000100 000004 0004
    5 0000000000000101 000005 0005
    6 0000000000000110 000006 0006
    7 0000000000000111 000007 0007
    8 0000000000001000 000010 0008
    9 0000000000001001 000011 0009
   10 0000000000001010 000012 000A
   11 0000000000001011 000013 000B
   12 0000000000001100 000014 000C
   13 0000000000001101 000015 000D
   14 0000000000001110 000016 000E
   15 0000000000001111 000017 000F
   16 0000000000010000 000020 0010
```