# Does bit-shifting in C only work on blocks of 32-bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, 32bit-64bit, bit-shift

I've been experimenting with C again after a while of not coding, and I have come across something I don't understand regarding bit shifting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
void main()
{
    uint64_t x = 0;
    uint64_t testBin = 0b11110000;
    
    x = 1 << testBin;
    
    printf("testBin is %"PRIu64"\nx is %"PRIu64"\n", testBin, x);
    //uint64_t y = 240%32;
    //printf("%"PRIu64 "\n",y);
}
```

In the above code, `x` returns 65536, indicating that after bit shifting 240 places the `1` is now sat in position 17 of a 32-bit register, whereas I'd expect it to be at position 49 of a 64-bit register.

I tried the same with `unsigned long long` types, that did the same thing.

I've tried compiling both with and without the `m64` argument, both the same.

Comment: dupe of [Unexpected C/C++ bitwise shift operators outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860538/unexpected-c-c-bitwise-shift-operators-outcome) or any others about left-shifting by >= the width of the type. I dunno why you expected shifting by 240 places to do anything meaningful or predictable.

Comment: You have two problems in the code: First, `1 << testBin` operates on an `int` that is likely 32 bits in your C implementation, because it uses the type of `1`, which is `int`, not the type this expression is being assigned to, `uint64_t`. Second, the C standard defines `<<` only for shifts less than the width of the type of the left operand, and 240 is too big for either `int` or `uint64_t`. A correct expression for what you want would set the type of the left operand and reduce the right operand modulo the width, so `(uint64_t) 1 << testBin % 64;`.

Comment: @underscore_d: This is not a duplicate because that question answers only one of the two problems here.

Comment: duplicates of the first problem: [Why does shifting 0xff left by 24 bits result in an incorrect value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46246411/995714), [Why does 1ul << 64 return 1 instead of 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37018469/995714), [Bitwise shift operation in C on uint64_t variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9290823/995714), [C left shift on 64 bits fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10048047/995714)

Comment: duplicates of the second problem: [What does the C standard say about bitshifting more bits than the width of type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11270492/995714), [When can bit shifting cause undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57617802/995714), [Shifting unsigned int more than the size of it, undefined or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45432694/995714)

Comment: @underscore_d I don’t expect it to do anything meaningful, it was merely a learning exercise. Originally it was `testBin << 1`, the result of which is obvious, I just wondered what would happen if I reversed it. I didn’t understand the result, thus the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup the constant `1` is a 32 bit integer. Thus the expression `1 << testBin` operates on 32 bits. You need to use a 64 bit constant to have the expression operate on 64 bits, e.g.:

```
x = (uint64_t)1 << testBin;
```

This does not change the fact that shifting by 240 bits is formally undefined behavior (even though it will probably give the expected result anyway). If `testBin` is set to `48`, the result will be well-defined. Hence the following should be preferred:

```
x = (uint64_t)1 << (testBin % 64);
```

Comment: just use `1ULL`. No need to cast

Comment: @phuclv That is a possibility, yes. I would say it is mostly a matter of taste/context. `unsigned long long` is specified to be *at least* 64 bits, but it may be more. In my opinion the explicit cast to a 64 bit integer is clearer in this case since that is the type the OP is using.

Answer (score -1):

It happens because if the default integer type of the constant `1`. It is integer (not long long integer). You need to use ULL postfix

```
x = 1ULL << testbin
```

PS if you want to shift 240 bits and your integer is less than it (maybe your implementation supports some giant inteters), it is an Undefined Behaviour)