# How to print the byte representations of a short int C object

Tags: c, int, byte, short

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print an int in binary representation using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024389/print-an-int-in-binary-representation-using-c)

How would I print the byte representations of a short int, and double in C.

As in lets say I have a function display_shortInt, how would I make it print the byte representation of a short int? I'm new to C, thanks you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this?

```
void print_bytes(void *p, size_t len)
{
    size_t i;
    printf("(");
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("%02X", ((unsigned char*)p)[i]);
    printf(")");
}

void print_short(short x)
{
    print_bytes(&x, sizeof(x));
}

void print_double(double x)
{
    print_bytes(&x, sizeof(x));
}
//etc.
```

That will print the bytes that form the value, in hexadecimal, two characters per byte.

For example, in a little-endian machine, `print_short(42)` will print `(2A00)`. In a big-endian machine it will be `(002A)`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way (i.e. using printf or another standard library function) to print it. You will have to write your own function.

```
void printbits(unsigned int v) {
   for (; v; v >>= 1) 
      putchar('0' + (v & 1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see how it is organised in memory (architecture-dependent):

```
short val = 0x1234;
printf( "%02x%02x", ((char*)&val)[0], ((char*)&val)[1] );
```

If you just want to see how it is written (big-endian):

```
printf( "%04x", val );
```

Comment: But note that if `char` is signed (and it is in many architectures), and the byte if greater than 0x80, you will get some funny values.